# Select ID from database as option value is not working in php

Tags: php

I am trying to build a data update program. But select ID from database as option values is not working in php. Also data from db can not be displayed in textarea. I visited two almost similar questions found in Stackoverflow, but unable to solve mine. Please someone guide me. My code is given below. Apart from that text box shows the encoding issue for Indian text.[Screen shot of the present state]

```
    <?php
include_once 'inclues/connection_string.php';
$id="7";
$Eng_Word="";
$As_Meaning="";
$New_Meaning="";
?>
<!doctype html>

<div class ="container">
    <div class="card p-3 bg-secondary">
        <form action = "update.php" method ="post">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label for="ID">SlNo</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                <option value="">Sl no</option>
                <?php
                    $stmt = "SELECT id FROM bengali";
                    $stmt= $conn->prepare($stmt);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
                    {
                    echo '<option value=' .$row['id'] . '>' . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['id']))
                    {
                    $id= $_POST['id'];
                    }
                else
                {
                    echo "Please select ID";
                }
                $stmt = "SELECT * FROM bengali WHERE id=$id";
                $stmt= $conn->prepare($stmt);
                $stmt->execute();
                $row=$stmt->fetch();
                $Eng_Word = $row['Eng_Word'];
                $As_Meaning = $row['As_Meaning'];
                $Bn_Meaning = $row['Bn_Meaning'];
            ?>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="Eng_Word">English Word</label>
                    <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $Eng_Word;?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="As_textarea">Assamese Meaning</label>
            <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $As_Meaning;?>" class="form-control">
            <hr>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="As_Meaning" id="AssameseMeaning" value="<?php echo $As_Meaning;?>" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Newtextarea">New Meaning</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Bn_Meaning" id="BengaliMeaning" value="<?php echo $Bn_Meaning;?>"  rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-right">Save Now!</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not using prepared statements correctly. You need to bind variables.

Comment: It's OK. I will learn more about it and try your instruction. Thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 0):

After the `execute` method you should store the result and bind it to a variable

```
<?php
    $stmt = "SELECT id FROM bengali";
    $stmt= $conn->prepare( $stmt );
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $std->bind_result( $id );

    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        printf( '<option value="%1$d">%1$d', $id );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Here the error message I got:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$d' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\update\inclues\update.php on line 25
The line 25 is:
printf( '<option value="%1$d">' %1$d, $id );

Comment: I edited the above a little while ago, I think the error you have should have been corrected

Comment: Still not working. This time error message is not there. But not working.

Comment: when you view the source code for this `select` are there errors? Have you got error reporting enabled? BTW - the SELECT menu needs a `name`

Answer (score 0):

Replace This code

```
echo '<option value=' .$row['id'] . '>' . '</option>';
```

to

```
echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[id]</option>";
```

Comment: The option value is working now. Can you help me in detecting why text are not displayed in textarea and also the encoding issue?

Comment: this line will help you  <textarea ><?= $As_Meaning;?></textarea>. compare with your code

Comment: Shringiraj, Thanks again. It works fine. Can you explain me why <?php $As_Meaning?> didn't work and use of "<?=" for my learning?

Comment: Basically it'<?=' is use to print $variable or string and <?= $a =?> is similar to <?php  echo $a ?>